# get SObject field name using the field label?

Tags: apex

When I google I find a lot of answers on how to get field label using field name.

For example:

```
SObjectType type = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = type.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Is it possible to do it like using a label to get the Field Name?

If I have a 'String Label' and I want to use this label to get the field Name from Some SObject. How should I do it?

Thanks for Helping!

Comment: labels can be duplicate whereas API name is unique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a method like this, which will take ObjectName and FieldLabel as input and return the FieldAPI.

Note that, field label can be duplicate so you need to take special care for this.

```
public static String getFieldAPIName (String objectName, String fieldLabel)
{
    SObjectType type = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = type.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(String strField:mfields.keySet())
    {
        SObjectField fl = mfields.get(strField);
        if(fieldLabel == fl.getDescribe().getlabel())
        {
            return strField;
        }
    }
}
```